# Accessing array elements in shell

Tags: arrays, shell

I have an array as:

```
Option[0]=$3
Option[1]=$4
Option[2]=$5
Option[3]=$6
Option[4]=$7
Option[5]=$8
```

I have to access array elements in shell script.

I know the format is `"${Option[0]}"` but this format is not accepted in my system.
Its giving me error "Bad substitution".

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: Its an embedded device, Linux 4.1.18-ts-armv7l

Comment: Which shell are you using?  `/bin/sh` may well not accept it.  Bash and Korn shell should both accept it.  One issue is "did the shell that rejects `"${Option[0]}"` accept `Option[0]=$3`?"

Comment: If it's an embedded device, it is quite possible that you have a Busybox shell, or maybe Dash — and those do not support the array notation.  Have you tried `$SHELL -x your-script.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` to review the output?

Comment: Yes m using "/bin/sh" and yes it didn't give any error on "Option[0]=$3"

Comment: Yes its Busybox shell

Comment: Look up the manual for the Busybox shell, then.  You or me?  Oh, it's your question…I think I'll let you do the legwork.  (If I knew the answer, I'd say, but I don't, so …)

Comment: Jonathan, it says "/bin/sh: SHELL: not found"

Comment: I suggested `$SHELL`; it looks like you probably left out the `$`.  But anyway, you need to find and read the Busybox shell manual.  There's a chance that if `Option[0]=$3` works, then `echo "$Option[0]"` will work, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: Thanks Jonhathan for pointing out the Busybox shell which I was missing, I have found a solution, mentioned in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution as:

Arrays are not possible in Busybox shell but a tweak is possible like:
`Option="$3; $4; $5; $6; $7; $8"`

I have used `;` because some of the elements were having "space in the string". Like `$3 = "    Hello World"`

And while iterating the array, delimeter was a space itself.
So to modify the delimiter `;` was used.

For iterating the above array:
`IFS=$';'
                        for opt in $Option
                        do
                                if [ $opt != " " ]; then
                                        echo "$opt"
                                fi
                        done`